# Remove € sign from string

Tags: php, magento

I use this code to display price inside a Magento shop:

```
<?php

    $myPrice = $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false);
    $zeros = substr($myPrice, -2);

    if(strval($zeros) == "00") {
        $myPrice = substr($myPrice, 0, -2);
        $myPrice = $myPrice . '-';
    }

    echo '<span class="price">'.$myPrice.'</span>';

?>
```

But I also want to remove the € sign from this string.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str_replace($search,$replace,$string)` might be the function you are looking for.

take a look at this line of code:

```
$myPrice = str_replace("€","",$myPrice);
```

this will search the string for € and replace it with an empty string, which means it removes the €.

[refer to the php documentation for further information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). i.e. you can also use arrays for $search and $replace (examples in the php doc)

full example:

```
<?php 
$myPrice = $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false);
$zeros = substr($myPrice, -2);
if(strval($zeros) == "00") { $myPrice = substr($myPrice, 0, -2);
$myPrice = $myPrice . '-'; }

$myPrice = str_replace("€","",$myPrice);
//or if the € is htmlencoded
$myPrice = str_replace("&euro;","",$myPrice);

echo '<span class="price">'.$myPrice.'</span>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! The price is now displayed with a space (&nbsp;) in front. How can I remove that space?

Comment: use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ;) like this: `$myPrice = str_replace("&nbsp;","",$myPrice);`

Answer (score 0):

Use php `str_replace` :-

```
str_replace("€","",$yourstring);
```

This function is `binary-safe`

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```